# MySQL: SELECT that i don't understand

Tags: mysql, database

Hi i need help about a SELECT that i don't understand, i'm a beginner developer i started  to work with MySQL like 2 weeks ago, so yeah im a noob , can someone help me with this SELECT:

- Say the name and surname of the clients whose surname contains more than 3 letters 'a'.

Comment: Can you show us a query you have tried?  Stack Overflow is not a free coding service.

Comment: where CONCAT(name,' ',surname) like '%a%a%a%'

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You haven't shown the definition of your table(s), without which it's hard to give a good answer.  See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)

Comment: If it was me, I'd go for the answer with two upvotes instead of two downvotes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
SELECT name,surname FROM `table_name` WHERE surname like '%a%a%a%'
```

Answer (score 3):

You achieve it as below:

```
select name,surname
FROM  your_table 
WHERE (length(surname)-length(replace(surname ,'a','')))/1 > 3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do somethink like this :

```
SELECT name,surname FROM your_table WHERE surnamelike '%a%a%a%'
```

Or this :

```
select name,surname FROM your_table WHERE (length(surname )-length(replace(surname ,'a','')))/1 >3
```